# Audiostreamer on iOS - Using with ARC

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, audiostreamer

I'm using matt gallagaher's AudioStreamer class. I've used it before in a project before ARC came along and it worked fine. When I added the class to a project which uses ARC, I came across lots of errors which I could fix by adding `__bridge` references etc...

So the app now runs, but when I start the streamer with `[streamer start]` I keep coming across this error which I don't know how to fix. The compiler stops at the function below in `Audiostreamer.m` with the error `Thread 8: EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=EXC_I386_BPT, subcode=0x0)` - I don't know what to do from here...please help.

```
if (CFReadStreamSetProperty(stream, kCFStreamPropertyHTTPShouldAutoredirect, kCFBooleanTrue) == false)
        {
            [self presentAlertWithTitle:NSLocalizedStringFromTable(@"File Error", @"Errors", nil)
                                message:NSLocalizedStringFromTable(@"Unable to configure network read stream.", @"Errors", nil)];
            return NO;
        }
```

Comment: Manually fixing files to work with ARC is not a good idea. Just disable ARC for those files. See [my answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10184307/batch-adding-fno-objc-arc-flag-to-multiple-source-files/10184313#10184313).

Comment: Thank you Evan, you are right, it's not a good. I have taken your advice and the app is working fine now, thanks for your help.

Comment: some fixing by hands and debuggers :)
you can try this: http://itux.idev.pro/2012/03/idevshort-audiostreamer-исправленный-для-arc/
or only download: http://itux.idev.pro/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/AudioStreamer_ARC_shared.zip

Comment: That's not enough info to go on. Mind posting more of your code?

Comment: I'm having this exact same problem, and I'm not using ARC for AudioStreamer. Is it really resolved for you, @Wasim?

Answer (score 2):

I have exactly error with using FreeStreamer by muhku (good library, recommended).
Check that you give correct/not nulled url to AudioStreamer.

Comment: Thanks for FreeStreamer lib, you have recommended

Answer (score 1):

Give my StreamingKit library a go. It has the same functionality as AudioStreamer but is built with ARC and has quite a few additionally pieces of functionality.

https://github.com/tumtumtum/StreamingKit

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same problem, but I disable arc and now is working fine, the only problem that I got is that when I slide my slider I get a new value to seekToTime: , but is not playing starting from the new value. Any idea what that is ?

Answer (score 0):

CoreAudio seems to work internally using exceptions, so if you have an exception breakpoint installed, this is what you will see. Just disable the breakpoints and it'll work.