# Enable/disable ARC for multiple files in xCode?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, automation, automatic-ref-counting

I have imported a lot of files with ARC into non-ARC iOS xCode project. There are also multiple targets in this project. So I need to add `-fobjc-arc` flags **manually** for each file in each target (in the opposite case it will be just another flag - `-fno-objc-arc`).

Could you advice a way how to make this process faster/semi-automatically? For example, is it possible to set flag for multiple files at once or to set flag for one file but for multiple targets?

Comment: is there a reason you didn't migrate to arc before importing?

Comment: This reason is simple - I'm not the owner of this project and so I don't have a permission to do that. And even if I'll do so - the same situation can happen - I'll have ARC project and I'll need to import non-ARC files.

Answer (score 0):

I found a similar question with answer:

[Batch adding "-fno-objc-arc" flag to (multiple) source files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10184307/batch-adding-fno-objc-arc-flag-to-multiple-source-files)

But I want to improve that answer slightly. You should add all the files you need to set flags into one folder with unusual exuding name. For example I used "OOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO". So it will be easier to find all these files in `Build Phases` tab.

Then as in that answer you can use <kbd>Shift</kbd> and/or <kbd>Command</kbd> to select these files and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to display the flag editor and add the necessary flags. Then you can rename the folder back with normal name.